# How to Manage Multiple Private Apps on Multiple play store of different customers using Android Management Apis?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise, android-enterprise-features

Hi Based on Documentation https://developers.google.com/android/management/apps

It's not clear how multiple play store accounts can be used, with Single Enterprise  that is created using Android Management API's

Suppose we build a solution using Android Management API's and now we have many customers each one will have there own set of private apps then how the app publication will work?

Where these customers/organisations will publish their apps ? if they use their own play store accounts to publish app then do we need to share our Emm's enterprise ID with them so that they can whitelist their private app's for our solution's enterprise ?

will it not leak apps among different customers ?

For Example 
There are two Organisations Alpha an Beta

Alpha published private app App  A & B and made it available to our EMM's Enterprise  ID

now Beta Published C & D using same steps

While creating Policy Alpha used Package name of A, B & C(somehow he got to know this package name) then will it not install app C in his policy ?

Please help Documentation is not very clear about app publication.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep separate approved apps, private apps and policies, you should create a separate Enterprise for each customer.

When a private app is published via [managed google play emm iframe](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9146439?hl=en&ref_topic=9496238), your organization is automatically whitelisted for that app. However when publishing via [Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139?hl=en&ref_topic=9496238) you have to target that app to your organization (enterprise id).

For example, two enterprises, Alpha and Beta:

> Alpha Enterprise has published private Apps A and B.  Apps A and B are by default whitelisted to Alpha Enterprise,
>
> Beta Enterprise has published private Apps C and D.  Apps C and D are by default whitelisted to Beta Enterprise.

If you try to add App C in your policy for Alpha Enterprise, it will not be installed unless Beta Enterprise whitelists App C to be available for Alpha Enterprise.

For a guide on publishing private apps, you may refer to this:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/topic/9496238

For distribution/whitelisting of private apps to other organizations (enterprises), you may check this link:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9495634?hl=en&ref_topic=6145152

Comment: Yes This will solve the problem but from docs it's was not very clear that we can create multiple enterprises. I figured it out only after creating multiple enterprises each using different email ID's.